# Unity Enemy AI script C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make an advanced enemy AI script in Unity, but I'm struggling with this a little bit. I've already imported the animations and all, but the scripting part doesn't go that well.

What I'm trying to do:
The NPC should walk (**isWalking**) within a certain radius, idle (**isIdle**) for a couple of seconds, then walk again (**isWalking**).

When the player gets inside the NPC's view radius, the NPC should run after the player (**isRunning**) and attack when the player is within close range (**isAttacking**). When the player is out of range, the NPC should play the second idle animation once (**isIdle2**), then go back to the first idle animation (**isIdle**).

And at last, when the E-key is pressed, the NPC should play the talk animation once (**isTalking**).

This is my current script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class guardAttack: MonoBehaviour 
{

  public Transform player;
  static Animator anim;

  // Use this for initialization
  public void Start() 
  {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  public void Update() 
  {
    Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;

    float angle = Vector3.Angle(direction, this.transform.forward);

    if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) < 10 && angle < 30) 
    {

      direction.y = 0;

      this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation,
        Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 0.1 f);

      anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);

      if ((direction.magnitude > 5)) 
      {
        this.transform.Translate(0, 0, 0.10 f);
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
        anim.SetBool("isTalking", false);
        anim.SetBool("isIdle2", false);

      } 
      else 
      {
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        anim.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
        anim.SetBool("isTalking", false);
        anim.SetBool("isIdle2", false);
      }

    } 
    else 
    {
      anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
      anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
      anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
      anim.SetBool("isIdle2", false);

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) 
      {
        anim.SetBool("isTalking", true);

      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: What's the actual question / issue?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to work with are finite state machines - and I do not mean Mecanim - for the AI logic. Here is a cool tutorial, that uses interfaces and will add up to your scripting "toolbox of knowledge". It might look a bit overwhelming, but if you give it a go, it will solve exactly what you are intending to do and help with other aspects in your game.

Just remember, this "reflex"-kind of behaviour is just scratching the surface in the area of AI.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/using-interfaces-make-state-machine-ai?playlist=17117